# How to manage your child's Google Family Link settings using a web browser

Tags: security, access-control, google-family-link

You're a parent.  You use [Google Family Link](https://families.google.com/familylink/) to help provide parental controls on your child's Chromebook and Android devices.

(As [Google admits](https://families.google.com/familylink/faq/), no parental-control software is perfect.  Therefore, you also keep all your child's devices in your own bedroom every night, until the child is old enough to need overnight smartphone access.)

It's true that you can use the "Family Link for Parents" app to change your child's Family Link rules.  This app works on Android and iOS.  But perhaps you'd rather not install any app.

How can you change your child's Family Link rules using a web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Log into the parent's Google account — not the child's Google account.
2. Visit https://familylink.google.com/.
3. Change whichever settings you'd like.

Some settings may be missing.  If you'd like to configure these settings, you may need to use the "Family Link for Parents" app.  [(Source.)](https://families.google.com/familylink/faq/)